# Using XPath causing problems

Tags: java, android, xpath, htmlcleaner

So I'm learning how to use XPath and HtmlCleaner to parse HTML but I have a problem. This is the code:

```
public class ScheudeleWithDesign extends Activity {

static final String urlToParse = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/18221";
static final String xpathTableContents = "//div[@id='text11']";
TextView tw1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scheudele_with_design);

    tw1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.urnikText);

    String value = "";
    value = new getScheudele().execute().toString();
    tw1.setText(value);

}//End of onCreate

private class getScheudele extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String stats = null;

        //cleaner properties
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
        props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(false);
        props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(false);
        props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
        props.setOmitComments(true);

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlToParse);
            TagNode root = cleaner.clean(url);
            Object[] node = root.evaluateXPath(xpathTableContents);
            //Vzemi podatke če najdeš element
            if (node.length > 0) {
                TagNode resultNode = (TagNode)node[10];
                stats = resultNode.getText().toString();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPatherException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stats;
    }

}
```

So I'm obviously trying to parse a certain data and set it as textview. This isn't working though, the result is completely wrong:

> com.whizzapps.stpsurniki.ScheudeleWithDesign$getScheudele@421a7d90

My guess is that the problem is in the XPath here:

```
static final String xpathTableContents = "//div[@id='text11']";
```

I've never worked with XPath before so I'm almost sure I screwed that part up. [This is the site](https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/18221) from which I'm trying to parse data by the way. This code should only get one table element for starters, once I know how to do it I'll parse the whole table.

Comment: The `"//div[@id='text11']"` XPath is trying to select any `div` element with an `id` attribute equal to `text11`, however there are no such `div` elements in the referenced HTML page.  (There are many div elements with class attributes set to `text11`.)  If you provide a specific example of the data you wish to select from the linked HTML page, we can help you craft the XPath.

Comment: @kjhughes I am still trying to learn XPath but I always have a problem learning new stuff that I know nothing about. Could you please show me an example on how to select ANY table content? Just show me an XPath code for any table content you want so that I somehow "get the structure". I appreciate it a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My guess is that the problem is in the XPath here:
>
> ```
> static final String xpathTableContents = "//div[@id='text11']";
> ```

As I mentioned in my comment, the `//div[@id='text11']` XPath is trying to select any `div` element with an `id` attribute equal to `text11`, however there are no such div elements in the referenced HTML page.

> Could you please show me an example on how to select ANY table
>   content? Just show me an XPath code for any table content you want so
>   that I somehow "get the structure".

Using the [HTML page you referenced](https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/18221), to select the div containing "2. ura", for example:

```
//*[@id="seznam_ur_teden"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[1]
```

To select just the text there,

```
//*[@id="seznam_ur_teden"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[1]/text()
```

To select the entire ancestral table:

```
//*[@id="seznam_ur_teden"]/table
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply, I didn't see it in my notifications for some reason. I tried all of those 3 codes but none work. The first error was because of the "seznam_ur_teden" since " can't be inside ". So I changed " with ', but it still doesn't work.

Comment: According to the [HTMLCleaner release notes](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/release.php) (release 2.0, but no improvements notes since), HTMLCleaner only partially implements XPath.  The XPaths I provided are correct and were tested in Chrome.  Maybe someone else who has struggled with HTMLCleaner's partial XPath implementation will have an insight, but my suggestion would be to use a tool where you're not left to wonder whether issues are with your XPath's or the tool's implementation of the standard.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take that advice :) I'll just simply clean my html with htmlcleaner and then parse it with jsoup, if that'll work.